# Traté de poner unas imágenes en el canvas. ¿Por qué no aparecen?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Les indexo el código

```js
var villaplatzi = document.getElementById("villaplatzi");
var ctx = villaplatzi.getContext("2d");
var fondo = {
  url:"tile.png",
  cargaOK: false,
}
var pollo = {
  url: "pollo.png",
  cargaOK: false,
}
var cerdo = {
  url: "cerdo.png",
  cargaOK: false,
}
var vaca = {
  url: "vaca.png",
  cargaOK: false,
}

var teclasVaca = {
  arriba: 38,
  abajo: 40,
  izquierda: 37,
  derecha: 39,
}

fondo.imagen = new Image();
fondo.imagen.src=fondo.url;
fondo.imagen.addEventListener("load",cargarFondo);

pollo.imagen = new Image();
pollo.imagen.src=pollo.url;
pollo.imagen.addEventListener("load",cargarPollo);

cerdo.imagen=new Image();
cerdo.imagen.src=cerdo.url;
cerdo.imagen.addEventListener("load",cargarCerdo);

vaca.imagen = new Image();
vaca.imagen.src=vaca.url;
vaca.imagen.addEventListener("load",cargarVaca);

function cargarFondo()
{
  fondo.cargaOK=true;
  dibujarImagen;
}
function cargarPollo()
{
  pollo.cargaOK=true;
  dibujarImagen;
}
function cargarCerdo()
{
  cerdo.cargaOK=true;
  dibujarImagen;
}
function cargarVaca()
{
  vaca.cargaOK=true;
  dibujarImagen;
}

function dibujarImagen()
{
  if(fondo.cargaOK)
    {ctx.drawImage(fondo.imagen,0,0);}
  if(pollo.cargaOK)
    {ctx.drawImagen(pollo.imagen,40,40)}
  if(cerdo.cargaOK)
    {ctx.drawImage(cerdo.imagen,80,80);}
  if(vaca.cargaOK)
    {ctx.drawImage(vaca.imagen,20,20);}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Villa Platzi</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width="500"height="500"id="villaplatzi"></canvas>
    <script src="platzi.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Abre la consola del navegador e indícanos si parece algún error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiene dos errores básicamente. Para llamar a la función `dibujarImagen` deberá hacerlo con los paréntesis `dibujarImagen();` en las funciones `cargarFondo`,`cargarPollo`,`cargarCerdo` y `cargarVaca`.

Y tiene un error al momento de dibujar el pollo, `drawImagen` no es correcto, es solo `drawImage` sin la letra **n** al final.